# How to attach libgdx actor to box2d body

Tags: libgdx, box2d, actor

I'm a newby, and I just started learning Libgdx and Box2d and creating game like hill climb racing. I created my car with the help of shapes and joints but I don't know how to attach graphics to it i used actors and sprites before for the sake of learning, but I don't know how to use it with Box2d boies. Any help is apprecieted!!

Comment: see http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/88471/55590

Comment: Maybe https://gist.github.com/nooone/8363982 helps. Note that in case you do not want the Actor to be "clickable", it's not necessary to override `hit`. Only `draw()` should be sufficient.